# Translate form fields using translation domain on Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, translation, xliff

I have a translations catalog on app/resources/translations/
menus.en.xliff, messages.en.xliff, user.en.xliff, ...

My form structure:

```html
public function buildform(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
 $builder
   ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'user.register', 'translation_domain' => 'user' ))
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
   $resolver->setDefaults(array(
   'data_class'         => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}
```

This method is valid but not the best.

I would like don't repeat 'translation_domain' => 'forms' on all the form fields.

I'm triying to pass the translation domain on configureOptions method but fail.

```html
public function buildform(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder
    ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'user.register'))

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
  $resolver->setDefaults(array(
  'data_class'         => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
  'translation_domain' => 'user'
   ));
}
```

But, when i write all the translations on messages.en.xliff all works.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It should be in setDefaultOptions not configureOptions:
http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/Form/AbstractType.html